# React design suggestion needed for validation inputs HOC vs Composition

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, higher-order-components

I'm using react and redux.

I'm having State less text inputs. which I can use like

`<TextInput error={true} /> // Uncontrolled and staelss`

So I can use the error/success... props by subscribing them to redux store. and also I want to provide an approach to do validation in local state for some simple cases where keeping that state in redux store will be complicated.

So I thought of two approaches.

Approach 1 HOC **withValidation**

```
const SomeInput = props => <TextInput label="Something" />;
const SomeInputWithValidation = withValidation(Input,(input) => {
   //perform validation logic
   return validation result.
  }); // Controlled ans stateful.
```

Approach 2 creating another component consuming the stateless, uncontrolled version

```
class ActiveTextInput extends React.Component { // Controlled and stateful.  

     //Do something with satate.

  render(){

     return <TextInput ...control props with state />;
  }
}
```

Please help me to choose the best abstraction. Thanks.

Comment: are you saying you want to validate the text of the Textinput Component(like valid email address) but are trying the best way since that component is its own controlled input element?

Comment: Thanks for your response @joey. I'm trying to create a best abstraction for doing validation. I have edited the question details as per your comment.